# Python automatic class assignment

Tags: python

In python. when I write `x = 5`, `x` becomes an instance of `int` automatically. But suppose I have defined a new class say `number` and I want `x` to become an instance of `number` instead of `int` when I assign it the value `5`. Is this possible?

ie, Instead of this -->

```
>>> x = 5
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
```

Is this possible:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> type(x)
<type 'number'>
```

Comment: No.  It cannot be done.  The important question is "why do you think you want to do this?" and "What's your **real** problem?"  What are you trying to do?  What problem do you have?  How can this possibly be a solution to that problem?  Please provide context for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you really should never do something like this. Jakob has the right answer, i.e. use `x = number(5)`.

However, that said, I wanted to try how it could be done in theory, and here's one solution in the form of a decorator:

```
import types

class number(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def replace_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return number(x)
    else:
        return x

def custom_numbers(f):
    code = f.func_code
    consts = tuple(map(replace_int, code.co_consts))
    new_code = types.CodeType(code.co_argcount, code.co_nlocals,
                              code.co_stacksize, code.co_flags,
                              code.co_code, consts, code.co_names,
                              code.co_varnames, code.co_filename,
                              code.co_name, code.co_firstlineno,
                              code.co_lnotab)
    return types.FunctionType(new_code, f.func_globals, f.func_name)
```

Any function you decorate, will end up using your custom number class:

```
@custom_numbers
def test():
    x = 5
    print type(x)


>>> test()
<class '__main__.number'>
```

The decorator works by replacing integer constants from the function's code-object with instances of the custom class. However, since `function.co_code` and `code.co_consts` are both read-only attributes, we have to create new code and function objects with the altered values.

One caveat is, that the values are assumed to be constants, so new instances are not created for each invocation of the function. If you mutate the value, that new value will be reflected in each subsequent call of the function.

Answer (score 5):

No. You would have to write a monkey patch to achieve this, that is incredibly unpythonic, can you simply not write

```
x = number(5)
```

:)

Comment: That is true that it can be simply achieved by writing `x = number(5)` but my program requirements are such that I want the former to happen. Anyways, is making/using that monkey patch simple or complicated?

Comment: You would basically have to re-write the backend of python ^^

Answer (score 1):

You would have to take advantage of [Python's language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) to compile the statement and then walk the AST replacing the objects as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `5` is an instance of `int`, `x` is just pointing to it. All variables in Python are references to objects. Thus, when you write `type(x)` you get the type of the object which `x` **holds a reference to**, in this case it is `int`.

If you assign another value to `x`, say `x = "string"`, `x` will hold a reference to that string object, and `type(x)` will return `<type 'str'>`.

Comment: Yes we are quite aware of this already what is the relativeness of this point?